# Update frame or revalidate/repaint panel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

How to update a Java frame with changed content?

I want to update a frame or just the panel with updated content. What do I use for this

Here is where I want to revalidate the frame or repaint mainpanel or whatever will work
I have tried a number of things, but none of them have worked.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("advance")) {
            multi--;
                    // Revalidate update repaint here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        }
        else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("reverse")) {
            multi++;
                    // Revalidate update repaint here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<       
        }
        else {
            openURL(e.getActionCommand());
        }

        }
```

Here is the whole java file

```
/*
 *
 *
 */ 

package build;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

/* 
 * ButtonDemo.java requires the following files:
 *   images/right.gif
 *   images/middle.gif
 *   images/left.gif
 */
public class StockTable extends JPanel
                        implements ActionListener {
    static int multi = 1;
    int roll = 0;
    static TextVars textvars = new TextVars();
    static final String[] browsers = { "firefox", "opera", "konqueror", "epiphany",
            "seamonkey", "galeon", "kazehakase", "mozilla", "netscape" };
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel mainpanel, panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4, panel2left, panel2center, panel2right;
        JButton stknames_btn[] = new JButton[textvars.getNumberOfStocks()];
    JLabel label[] = new JLabel[textvars.getNumberOfStocks()];
    JLabel headlabel, dayspan, namelabel;
    JRadioButton radioButton;
    JButton button;
    JScrollPane scrollpane;
    int wid = 825;
    public JPanel createContentPane() {

        mainpanel = new JPanel();
        mainpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(wid, 800));
        mainpanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(wid, 25));
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
        mainpanel.add(panel1, c);

        // Panel 2------------
        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(wid, 51));
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
        mainpanel.add(panel2, c);
        panel2left = new JPanel();
        panel2left.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(270, 51));
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
        panel2.add(panel2left, c);
        panel2center = new JPanel();
        panel2center.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(258, 51));
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
        panel2.add(panel2center, c);
        panel2right = new JPanel();
        panel2right.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(270, 51));
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
        panel2.add(panel2right, c);
        // ------------------

        panel3 = new JPanel();
        panel3.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        scrollpane = new JScrollPane(panel3);
        scrollpane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(wid, 675));
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
        mainpanel.add(scrollpane, c);


            ImageIcon leftButtonIcon = createImageIcon("images/right.gif");

            //b1 = new JButton("Disable middle button", leftButtonIcon);
            //b1.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
            //b1.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.LEADING); //aka LEFT, for left-to-right locales
            //b1.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
            //b1.setActionCommand("disable");


            //Listen for actions on buttons 1
            //b1.addActionListener(this);

            //b1.setToolTipText("Click this button to disable the middle button.");

            //Add Components to this container, using the default FlowLayout.
            //add(b1);


        headlabel = new JLabel("hellorow1");
            c.gridx = 0;       
            c.gridy = 0;       
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        panel1.add(headlabel, c);

        radioButton = new JRadioButton("Percentage");
            c.gridx = 2;       
            c.gridy = 0;       
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        panel1.add(radioButton, c);

        radioButton = new JRadioButton("Days Range");
            c.gridx = 3;      
            c.gridy = 0;      
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        panel1.add(radioButton, c);

        radioButton = new JRadioButton("Open / Close");
            c.gridx = 4;       
            c.gridy = 0;       
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0,0 );
        panel1.add(radioButton, c);


        button = new JButton("<<");
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        button.setActionCommand("reverse");
        button.addActionListener(this);
            c.gridx = 0;       
            c.gridy = 1;       
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
            panel2left.add(button, c);

        dayspan = new JLabel("hellorow2"); 
        dayspan.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER); 
        dayspan.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        dayspan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(270, 50)); 
            c.gridx = 1;       
            c.gridy = 1;
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);       
            panel2center.add(dayspan, c);

        button = new JButton(">>");
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        button.setActionCommand("advance");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        if (multi == 0) {
            button.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else {
            button.setEnabled(true);
        }
            c.gridx = 2;       
            c.gridy = 1;       
        c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
            panel2right.add(button, c);

        int availSpace_int = textvars.getStocks().size()-textvars.getNumberOfStocks()*7;

        ArrayList<String[]> stocknames = textvars.getStockNames();
        ArrayList<String[]> stocks = textvars.getStocks();
        for (int column = 0; column < 8; column++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < textvars.getNumberOfStocks(); row++) { 

                if (column==0) {
                    if (row==0) {
                        namelabel = new JLabel(stocknames.get(0)[0]); 
                        namelabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                        namelabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                        namelabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
                        c.gridx = column;
                        c.gridy = row;
                        c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
                        panel3.add(namelabel, c);
                    }
                    else {
                        stknames_btn[row] = new JButton(stocknames.get(row)[0], leftButtonIcon); 
                        stknames_btn[row].setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
                        stknames_btn[row].setActionCommand(stocknames.get(row)[1]); 
                        stknames_btn[row].addActionListener(this);
                        stknames_btn[row].setToolTipText("go to Google Finance "+stocknames.get(row)[0]); 
                        stknames_btn[row].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
                        c.gridx = column;
                        c.gridy = row;
                        c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
                        //scrollpane.add(stknames[row], c);
                        panel3.add(stknames_btn[row], c);
                    }
                }
                else {
                        label[row]= new JLabel(textvars.getStocks().get(columnMulti(multi))[1]);
                        label[row].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
                        label[row].setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                        label[row].setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                        label[row].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));    
                        c.gridx = column;
                        c.gridy = row;
                        c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
                        panel3.add(label[row], c);
                }

            }
        }

        return mainpanel;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("advance")) {
            multi--;
        }
        else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("reverse")) {
            multi++;        
        }
        else {
            openURL(e.getActionCommand());
        }

        }

        /** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
        protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
            java.net.URL imgURL = StockTable.class.getResource(path);
            if (imgURL != null) {
                    return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
            } else {
                    System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
                    return null;
            }
        }

    public static void openURL(String url) {
        String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
        try {
            if (osName.startsWith("Mac OS")) {
                Class<?> fileMgr = Class.forName("com.apple.eio.FileManager");
                Method openURL = fileMgr.getDeclaredMethod("openURL",
                    new Class[] {String.class});
                openURL.invoke(null, new Object[] {url});
                        }
            else if (osName.startsWith("Windows")) {    
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + url);
            }
            else { //assume Unix or Linux
                boolean found = false;
                for (String browser : browsers)
                    if (!found) {
                        found = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                        new String[] {"which", browser}).waitFor() == 0;
                        if (found) 
                            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {browser, url}); 
                    }   
                    if (!found)
                        throw new Exception(Arrays.toString(browsers));
                    }
                }   
        catch (Exception e) {   
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Error attempting to launch web browser\n" + e.toString());
        }
    }
    int reit = 0;
    int start = textvars.getStocks().size()-((textvars.getNumberOfStocks()*5)*7)-1;
    public int columnMulti(int multi) {
        reit++;
        start++;
        if (reit == textvars.getNumberOfStocks()) {
            reit = 0;
            start=start+64;
        }
        //start = start - (multi*(textvars.getNumberOfStocks()));
        return start;
    }

        /**
        * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety, 
        * this method should be invoked from the 
        * event-dispatching thread.
        */
        private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        //Create and set up the window.
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stock Table");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            //Create and set up the content pane.
            StockTable newContentPane = new StockTable();
            //newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
            //frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane.createContentPane());
        frame.setSize(800, 800);


            //Display the window.
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);


        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
            //creating and showing this application's GUI.
            javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        createAndShowGUI(); 
                    }
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to update?

Comment: I would like to update the mainpanel with the changed content, the same as what is displayed initially but with different numbers for the table and radio buttons changed and setenabled changed for the advance4 and reverse buttons basically rerun createContentPane() and update the mainpanel without a new frame

Comment: do i need to use super, i am not clear on how to perform this

Comment: `frame.setSize(800, 800); .. frame.pack();`  Since calling `pack()` will resize the frame to the smallest size needed to display the content, that order of calls is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment you find yourself wanting to "re-create" a UI based on a small change, should raise alarm bells.  There are situations when this is going to be a good idea, but in most cases, it's a sign of a bad design.

Let's start with...

```
frame.setContentPane(newContentPane.createContentPane());
```

This is a bad idea.  You create a `JPanel` just to create another `JPanel`.  All of sudden, you've not lost context to the UI.

Instead of the `createContentPane`, simple construct you UI from the constructor of the `StockTable` pane and add that to the frame...More like...

```
frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
```

Get rid of `mainPanel` and use the `StockTable` panel directly.

I can't run your code, but it looks speciously like your trying to "emulate" a table layout.  Instead, simplify your life and learn to use [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).  Updating the table more be significantly easier (not to mention look nicer) if you do...

Comment: I didnt know jtable was an option I will use your advice

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is if you want to update a `swing component` always use the Event Dispatcher Thread.

I think this may helps you

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("advance")) {
            multi--;

                   Runnable edt = new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       /*Update your components here*/
                       }
                   };

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(edt);
          }
        else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("reverse")) {
            multi++;
            Runnable edt= new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      /*Update your components here*/
                     }
                };

                 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(edt);
        }
        else {
            openURL(e.getActionCommand());
        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: What do I use wihtin /*update components here*/ to make this if statement if (multi == 0) {
            button.setEnabled(false);
        } work
        else {
            button.setEnabled(true);
        }

Comment: if i use mainpanel.removeAll() what will make the mainpanel reload the information in the first method